# What are the minimum conditions for the tangent plane to a surface to be defined, the chain rule to work, and directional derivatives?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

1) Is the tangent plane at a point on a surface defined if the surface is differentiable at the point, or does it need to be $C^1$?

2) For the chain rule to work, does it need to be $C^1$, or just differentiable?

3) And for directional derivatives, does it need to be $C^1$, or just differentiable?

Reading some material I don't find any conclusive answers to the above questions.
I don't need detailed answer.but you can give me a hint.

Comment: Thanks for your edit @Kundor

Comment: Can you define what you mean by a surface being differentiable at a point? The chain rule works whenever the derivatives exist (have you seena proof?). Directional derivatives may exist a every point without the function being continuous at the point.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff I didn't write properly, I meant for a tangent plane to a surface at a given point is define when the condition of being derivable is true.I think is true because differentiability arise from Taylor formula hence for a level surface if it its differentiable then you can approximate a point by a plane.but I am not totally sure.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff what you mean by whenever the derivatives exist?the partials exists?(I know that its not sufficient) being differenciable?or $c^1$?

Comment: I should've said "the differentials" "$Df(a)$, $Dg(f(a))$.